# why do these sounds make a dog unhappy?

Tags: audio, frequency

This is an odd one. I'm not sure it's the right place to ask, but maybe there are some sound experts who can chime in? (no pun intended)

We use [two sounds](https://soundcloud.com/user-919494216/sets/alfie-take-2) on our website to indicate success and failure on a quiz. Those are very simple and short sounds.

Somehow one of our customers reported that her dog was whimpering and really upset with both of those sounds. He's normally fine with lots of other sounds that dogs are typically unhappy with including loud sounds, hoovers etc. She even said it happens when she uses headphones!

Other than muting, or replacing those sounds (and upsetting other dogs?), is there anything we can do to clean the sound or detect what specifically makes them upset this or other dogs?

**Downvoters**: I think this question crosses over between biology/physiology/physics and signal and audio processing. The answers I'm getting now actually demonstrate this. It requires this cross-domain knowledge. In any case, I'm happy to delete it if this seems to not jive well with this community. I think my intentions were positive and I added a bounty to try to solve this real problem. It saddens me to even see downvotes for the answers although they made an effort to help.

EDIT: I'm unable to delete this question it seems. I get an error message.

[image: cannot delete question]

EDIT2: In case it's more helpful, here's a spectrum analysis of both sounds using Audacity. There are lots of different options, but this is using the default options for Analyze->Plot spectrum

[image: fail2 sound]

[image: success2 sound]

Comment: curious about the downvote... yes, it's an odd question, but I think an interesting / valid one. I tried to provide clear and concise information. It's a real problem that affects someone, and I'm trying to get some hints on how to resolve it...

Comment: I guess your question is downvoted because here's a place for computer software and hardware functioning related questions, and your question is rather from physics or biology domains. So ask them on  appropriate SO sections: https://physics.stackexchange.com/ https://biology.stackexchange.com, and regarding your question, I would recommend you to check your sound's frequency range: dogs do not like sounds with loud high frequencies

Comment: This is a Strange Question

Comment: Thanks @SergeyLebedev. Your comment is far far(!) more helpful than silent downvotes. Thank you. Yes, I wrote that I wasn't sure if this is the best place to ask. I think it's in the area between physics/biology and software (e.g. what kind of filters or checks can be applied via software to detect or prevent the problem). I will try to post it there instead, but I wasn't even aware of those sites until now.

Comment: regarding the frequency, I don't think it's very high, but I have zero knowledge about sounds/frequencies etc, so I'm not even sure *what* to look for.

Comment: @gingerlime your sounds contains multiple frequencies, and among them there possible can be those high ones that upset the dog. You can explore it yourself with sound spectrum diagram in some audio redactor, for example `Audacity`: http://manual.audacityteam.org/man/plot_spectrum.html

Comment: The simple answer would be, how would you react for the sound of 
an leaking faucet and the sound of leaking filter tap, find anything common? they are identical and more importantly we would be able to recognize them since we are aware of our surroundings. Same goes with dogs they can recognize different sounds relate them to the sounds they like or don't like. For me there are some sounds make me unhappy, feel bad and some make me feel good. This link from youtube https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7AnWYa7gYvc has tones that dogs may like. You can find or tweak your sounds by referring to it.

Comment: Thanks @SergeyLebedev. That's also super useful. I'll try it out and see if I can spot anything. Also thanks Vikram Palakurthi. So far I'm already getting useful ideas... and downvotes. Go figure. I can't delete the question because it has a bountry. I did post it also on https://biology.stackexchange.com/q/71869/15579 where it seems to be appreciated some

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This question is not at the right place (and down-voted) but for your information you may take a look on [Frequency Range of Dog Hearing](https://hypertextbook.com/facts/2003/TimCondon.shtml) where you can read that:

> Humans can hear sounds approximately within the frequencies of **20 Hz and 20,000 Hz**
>
> [...]
>
> The frequency range of dog hearing is approximately **40 Hz to 60,000 Hz**

Note also that:

> The shape of a dog's ear also helps it hear more proficiently.

A similar example is :

> A vacuum cleaner, which merely sounds loud to us, can produce a high frequency sound which may scare dogs away

I expect that very low frequency can also scare dog (like thunderstorm sound)

---

You may use a [spectrum analyser](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spectrum_analyzer) software (open source audio-software like [Audacity](https://www.audacityteam.org/) allow you to do the job) to double check if low/high frequency are present in the sound.

In my opinion you may use [a Band-pass filter](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Band-pass_filter), to **cut all frequency**  **lower than 50KHz** & **higher than 15KHz** to avoid the "the vacuum cleaner" and "thunderstorm sound" effect (which may scare dogs.)

You may finally take a look on the [Audacity low pass filter manual](http://manual.audacityteam.org/man/low_pass_filter.html) to know how to apply this filter on your sound.

Comment: Thanks a lot. To me the answer just shows that the question *is* in the right place. I don't think many people in Biology or Physics have this specific knowledge of how to fix this sound. The customer said that this dog isn't affected by thunderstorms or vacuum cleaners, interestingly, but somehow was affected by these sounds. Weird... In any case, I'll definitely try to follow your tips and see what I can find.

Comment: It sound strange that the dog is not affected by thunderstorms ... if sound affect only one dog, it may be also possible that this specific dog have a shape of ear and/or the neural network part - which treat sound - a little bit altered relatively to other dog (genetic have effect on both physical & neuronal part )...

Comment: Sorry, I checked again what our customer reported, and she didn't mention thunderstorms, but she did mention that he's not bothered particularly by "fireworks, fire alarms, screaming kettles, music of all kinds and even tolerates the vacuum" ... Judging by another commenter on biology exchange, it might unique to this dog, but sample size is still pretty small. I know of 1 dog affected by those particular sounds, but 3 others who don't seem to ...

Comment: Agree that you need more sample to generalize... I hope that low/high band pass solve this. I note also that the fail2 sound really look like a dog barking, you may probably better just change this fail sound with another one.

Comment: Thanks. Yes, we were considering simply changing the sounds, but then since it was an isolated complaint, and since we didn't have the knowledge/tools to know why it happens, my colleagues were saying "but what if the new sound also annoys other dogs?" (roughly)... So I hope to understand better potential causes, and then it's easier to fix this. I was genuinely curious about this, but sadly lack either domain knowledge.

Comment: Avoid sound which may be interpreted as a dog barking :-) Regards

Comment: I tried with audacity, and even downloaded and installed an [extra filter](https://forum.audacityteam.org/viewtopic.php?f=42&t=70697), but I'm pretty lost with the settings and values to make sure I do the right thing to apply a band-pass filter with those values.

Comment: I update my answer with a link to audacity manual to apply band pass filter: Use menu Effect > Low Pass Filter

Answer (score 0):

*Despite the fact that the question is offtopic here, I'll move here my initial answer from comments - I guess this will allow the question author to close question bounty properly.*

The answer:
1. I guess your question is downvoted because here's a place for computer software and hardware functioning related questions, and your question is rather from physics or biology domains. So ask them on appropriate SO sections: [physics.stackexchange.com](https://physics.stackexchange.com/) and/or [biology.stackexchange.com](https://biology.stackexchange.com/)

2. Regarding your question, I would recommend you to check your sounds frequency range: dogs do not like sounds with loud high frequencies. Perhaps your sounds contains high frequencies, you can check it yourself with sound spectrum diagram in some audio redactor, for example [Audacity](http://manual.audacityteam.org/man/plot_spectrum.html)
3. And yes, as @astefani pointed out those frequencies can be removed with band-pass filter, for example with [low-pass filter](http://manual.audacityteam.org/man/low_pass_filter.html) in Audacity

Comment: Thanks again Sergey! I find both your and @astefani's answers very useful, and I do still feel that it belongs here. The type of software and processes to fix and analyze sound are very much software-related and not purely in the biological / physics realm in my opinion.

Comment: It was a hard call which answer to accept, and where to award the bounty, since both answers were very helpful. I picked the first one, but both are great. Thanks again, Sergey!